# XSLT - Add a XML node as header

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xml-parsing, mule

In my flow I receive a list of `XML objects` like this example:

```
<shop>..data..</shop>
<shop>..data..</shop>
<shop>..data..</shop>
<shop>..data..</shop>
```

I want to add a header/node like this:

```
<shops "xmlns": "http://www.demo.com","shops-id": "static-value">
    <shop>..data..</shop>
    <shop>..data..</shop>
    <shop>..data..</shop>
    <shop>..data..</shop>
</shops>
```

Is possible to add that with XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much depends on context, but one way of doing it would be to create a template matching the first occurrence of `shop` in any list, like this:

```
<xsl:template match="shop[1]">
  <shops>
    <xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::shop"/>
  </shops>
</xsl:template>
```

(I haven't added the attributes because your sample output isn't valid XML)

And then add a second template to match the remaining `shop` elements and discard them, like this:

```
<xsl:template match="shop"/>
```

There may be more efficient methods depending on exactly what you're trying to do, but this approach will create a new `shops` element within any element that contains any `shop` elements.